# How to multiply certain elements of an array by different sclars in Python

Tags: python, arrays

For example, if I have an array of np.ones(N), the array will be shaped vertically.

Next, I would do
for i in range(1,int(N/2)):
(this is where I want to multiply half the array by a certain constant)
for i in range(int(N/2),int(N)):
(this is where I want to multiply the other half of the array by a different constant)

How would I do this?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2):

Use array indexing

**Example**

```
import numpy as np

N = 6
arr = np.ones(N)   # All ones

arr[:N//2] *= 2    # Multiply first half by 2
arr[N//2:] *= 4    # Multiply second half by 4

print(arr):        # Out: [2. 2. 2. 4. 4. 4.]
```